# Вызов нового фрагмента с закрытием текущего

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

Мне надо вызвать из одного фрагмента, другой фрагмент, в котором по кнопке надо взывать 3й фрагмент. Всё это в пределах одной активности. Т.е. в активность передаётся только 1й фрагмент. Потом в этом фрагменте нажимаю на кнопочку и открывается другой фрагмент, закрывая предыдущий. 
Но когда я пытаюсь сделать так в Fragment1, что бы вызывать Fragment2, то у меня просто вылетает:

```
Fragment2 fragment2 = new FragmentZn();
Fragment1 fr = new Fragment1();
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_choose, null);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    btn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment2)
                    .remove(fr)
                    .commit();
        }
    });}
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, что выдает logcat

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко Под слово "вылетает" я имел ввиду немного не то, за что прошу прощение. Он просто выходит из текущей активности назад в MainActivity и ощущение, что он заново запускает приложение

Comment: Так речь идет обработке нажатия на кнопку (Button) или на нажатия на кнопку назад?

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко нажав на (Button) он вылетает из текущей активности, возвращаясь в MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было просто сделать так:

```
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, fragment2, "TAG")
                        .commit();
```

R.id.container - один и тот же контейнер, из которого я вызывал Fragment1. Я же открывал в новом контейнере в активности, вот оно и не заменялось.